Can the Slack API Post Files to a Channel?
I'm creating a slackbot for the first time. It's super simple at the moment, basically just posts text when a user types in a command.
I want to have the slackbot post a file in a channel. This bot will generate some JSON files and send them back to the user depending on their command. Is this possible?
If not, and the bot has to post the JSON as text, is there a way to format the text generated so the JSON would not be split into separate messages if it is too large?

Slack's API is fairly well documented, and even has a whole label just for files: https://api.slack.com/methods?filter=files
